# OpenGL: drawing lightning source

Tags: opengl, draw, light

I am in front a simple issue, but I can't find a way to solve it:

I have the coordinates of a lightning source. I would like to draw a white circle centered on this lightning source.

How can I do that? Is there a opengl function or I should add manually verteces to create a circle?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW I think you would be better to ignore all this stuff about lightning just make this question "I would like to draw a white circle centered on some coordinates. How can I do that? Is there a opengl function or should I manually add vertices to create a circle?".

Comment: Did you mean "lighting" instead of "lightning"?

Comment: Both of you are right!!

(my english!!)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL does not have primitives like circles. It only has triangles, fundamentally.

Your best options are either to make a regular n-gon where n is large enough to satisfy you, or make the circle geometry part of a texture, and just render a square where some of the coordinates are transparent.

Which is most appropriate depends entirely on context.

Answer (score 0):

Use Blender to create a simple circle mesh. Export to one of the available object files, load it in your app and render. You can use Assimp to load the mesh or write your own loader. You can find a lot of examples online on how to do this.